Angular build issue on meta tags
When i run build:ssr it generates everything fine except og:image url, What can be a reason?
for example og:url is fetched successfully, but og:image not, my main goal is to fetch correct gif successfully. and it works fine when i check with inspect element.
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogPost } from 'src/app/shared/interfaces/blog-post.interface';
import { DataSharingService } from 'src/app/shared/service/data-sharing.service';
import { MetaTagsService } from 'src/app/shared/service/meta-tags.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-detail',
  templateUrl: './blog-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-detail.component.scss']
})
export class BlogDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  public blog: BlogPost;
  public gifUrl: any;
  isBrowser = false;
  relatedPost: BlogPost[] = [];
  title: string = '';
  gif: { title: string, src: string } | null = null;
  private listJsonData: any;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataSharingService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private metaService: MetaTagsService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadListJson().then(() => {
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        const blogId = params['id'];
        this.title = params['title'];
        this.fetchGif(this.title).then(() => {
          this.fetchBlogDetail(blogId);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  async loadListJson(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.listJsonData = await this.http.get('/api/list.json').toPromise();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to load list.json:', error);
    }
  }

  fetchBlogDetail(blogId: string): void {
    this.dataService.getBlogDetail(blogId).subscribe(blog => {
      this.blog = blog;
      const gifUrl = this.gif?.src ? this.convertWebmToGif(this.gif.src) : this.getGifUrlFromListJson(this.title);

      console.log('gifUrl:', gifUrl); // Add this line

      if (gifUrl) {
        this.gifUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(gifUrl);
      }

      // Pass the correct gifUrl to updateMetaTags
      this.updateMetaTags(gifUrl);
      
      this.metaService.updateStructuredData(this.blog);
    });
  }

  updateMetaTags(gifUrl: string): void {
    const absoluteImageUrl = gifUrl ? `https://website.com${gifUrl}` : 'no image';
    
    const meta = {
      title: this.blog?.meta?.title ?? this.blog?.title ?? 'No title available',
      description: this.blog?.meta?.description ?? this.blog?.intro ?? 'No description available',
      keywords: this.blog?.meta?.keywords ?? '',
      image: absoluteImageUrl
    };

    console.log('Updating meta tags with:', meta);

    this.metaService.updateMetaTags(meta, meta.image);
  }

  async fetchGif(title: string): Promise<void> {
    if (!title) {
      console.error('Title parameter is undefined');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const gif = await this.http.get<{ title: string, src: string }>(`/api/gifsfetch?index=${title}`).toPromise();
      this.gif = gif;
      const gifUrl = this.convertWebmToGif(gif.src);
      this.gifUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(gifUrl);

      // Update meta tags with the GIF URL immediately after fetching
      this.updateMetaTags(gifUrl);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch gif:', error);
    }
  }

  getGifUrlFromListJson(title: string): string | null {
    if (!this.listJsonData) {
      return null;
    }

    const item = this.listJsonData.find((entry: any) => entry.title === title);
    return item ? this.convertWebmToGif(item.src) : null;
  }

  convertWebmToGif(url: string): string {
    return url.replace('.webm', '.gif');
  }

  getFilterBlogs(type: string) {
    this.router.navigate(['/blogs', type.toLocaleLowerCase()]);
  }

  isVideo(url: string): boolean {
    return /\.(mp4|webm|ogg)$/i.test(url);
  }
}


import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject, catchError, map, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { BlogPost } from '../interfaces/blog-post.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSharingService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://website.com/api';

  // path = '/assets/data/data.json'
  path = `https://keval101.github.io/blog-json/db.json`;

  changedSlides$ = new Subject();
  blogs: BlogPost[] = [];
  
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any
  ) { }

  getBlogs(): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
    return this.http.get<BlogPost[]>(this.path).pipe(
      map((res: any) => res?.blog || []),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getBlogDetail(blogId: string | number): Observable<BlogPost | undefined> {
    return this.http.get<BlogPost[]>(this.path).pipe(
      map((res: any) => res.blog.find(item => item.id == blogId)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  getBlogByTypes(blogType: string): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
    return this.http.get<BlogPost[]>(this.path).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res?.blog.filter(x => x?.tags?.join(',').toLowerCase().includes(blogType.toLowerCase()));
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
  fetchGifByTitle(title: string): Observable<{ title: string, src: string }> {
    return this.http.get<{ title: string, src: string }>(`${this.apiUrl}/gifs?title=${title}`);
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
    let errorMessage = 'Unknown error!';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}


This is my meta-tags.service.ts


import { Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { isPlatformBrowser, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

export interface IMetaTags {
  description: string;
  keywords: string;
  
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MetaTagsService {
  private isBrowser: boolean = false;
  private pageUrl: string = '';

  constructor(
    private _meta: Meta,
    
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private dom: any
  ) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
  }

  createCanonicalLink(url?: string): void {
    const canURL = url ? url : this.dom.URL;
    this.pageUrl = canURL.replace('http', 'https').replace('httpss', 'https');
    const canonicalElement = this.dom.querySelector('link[rel="canonical"]');
    if (canonicalElement) {
      canonicalElement.href = this.pageUrl;
    } else {
      const link: HTMLLinkElement = this.dom.createElement('link');
      link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
      link.setAttribute('href', this.pageUrl);
      this.dom.head.appendChild(link);
    }
  }

  updateMetaTags(meta: IMetaTags, ogImageUrl?: string): void {
    
    this.createCanonicalLink();
    meta.keywords = `${meta.keywords}, Personal Blogging, Blog Contents, Blogs, Finance, Social, Sports, Quick Blogs`;

    this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: meta.description }, "name='description'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: meta.keywords }, "name='keywords'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'image', content: ogImageUrl || '' }, "name='image'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'robots', content: 'index, follow' }, "name='robots'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'QuickBlogs' }, "property='og:site_name'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:locale', content: 'en_US' }, "property='og:locale'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'website' }, "property='og:type'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: this.pageUrl }, "property='og:url'");
    
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: meta.description }, "property='og:description'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image:secure_url', content: ogImageUrl || '' }, "property='og:image:secure_url'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: ogImageUrl || '' }, "property='og:image'");
    this._meta.updateTag({ name: 'author', content: 'QuickBlogs Team' }, "name='author'");

    console.log('Meta tags updated:', {
     
      description: meta.description,
      keywords: meta.keywords,
      image: ogImageUrl
    });
  }

  

}



When i inspect there is correctly updated meta tags :
but in the sources
What can be a reason?

You have a lot of unrelated code but not the relevant one. Please create a minimal reproducible example and clarify the problem. Also og:image is not part of the code.

@JSONDerulo i have updated description and i have added meta-tags.service.ts
